# Perl debugger on test modules

Tags: perl, debugging, testing

I'm running into problems testing a new addition to a module. (Specifically - the ~ operator seems to be not working in Math::Complex for this new feature only.)  It's too bizarre to be what it appears but the ideal scheme would be to add the -d option on the top line of the .t program.

Well, I was quickly disabused of **that** idea! It does not invoke the debugger.

If I wanted to use the debugger, I'd need to create an edit of the .t program that:

- Uses (the use command) the module directly. not in the form of
  BEGIN { use_ok('My::Module') };
- Does not "use Test::More;"
- A few other edits that cause gluteal pains

The problem with doing that is that any changes I make in the edited test program I still need to transfer back to the true test program use in "make test".  Error prone as best.

I am already using "make test TEST_VERBOSE=1" so that my stdio output shows up.  But there's GOT to be a simpler way to invoke the debugger on the .t

Thanks for ideas here.

-- JS

Answer (score 1):

use_ok tests are great, but you should have them in test files of their own, not test files that also test other things.

I'm not sure why you would need to avoid Test::More or use_ok to run the debugger, though.  What does happen when you try your test directly:

```
perl -d -Mblib t/yourtestfile.t?
```

If all else fails, you can try using [Enbugger](http://p3rl.org/Enbugger) in your test script.

Comment: OK, in the top level of the directory structure for the module, so that both lib and t are subdirectories of .

Comment: not lib, blib/lib, blib/arch, etc., where `make` or `Build` copies/builds the module before installation. You can actually do it in the t directory too (blib.pm will look up several levels for a blib directory)

Comment: OK, in the top level of the directory structure for the module, so that both lib and t are subdirectories of .


$ perl -Mblib=lib t/MyTestModule.t
Cannot find blib even in lib/../../../../..
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.


With -d option I get similarly unhelpful results.

I don't want to "require Enbugger" in the make test; I want to run/debug the test module directly.  It's much cleaner that way.


BTW I *did* debug the test module by the brute force I wanted to avoid. But there's gotta be a better way.

Comment: you have to run make first (not make test, just make) to build the blib directory.  and it should be -Mblib, not -Mblib=lib